# Laravel 5.2 - caching, pagination and random order

Tags: json, caching, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

I have to display posts on multiple pages, but I want the order be always different. Unfortunately `inRandomOrder()` can give already displayed items by requesting another page, and `orderBy(DB::raw('RAND(aseed)')` or `orderByRaw('RAND(aseed)')` (with a session constant `aseed`) are database specific and slow on a big dataset.

I decided to cache the array containing the ids of the posts to be displayed, then shuffle it and retrieve it for pagination.

A simple example in tinker:

```
>>>$posts_ids = Post::pluck('id')->shuffle();
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#835
 all: [
   8,
   6,
   1,
   2,
   4,
   7,
   3,
   5,
 ],
}


>>>$sliced_ids = $posts_ids->slice(0,2)->all();
=> [
 8,
 6,
]

>>> Post::whereIn('id',$posts_ids->slice(0,2)->all())->get();

=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#865
 all: [
   App\Post {#883
     id: 6,
     ...
   },
   App\Post {#881
     id: 8,
     ...
   }
 ],
 }
```

The posts returned by `whereIn` (also by `findMany`) method are in ascending order, 'cause is like to use a where clause `...WHERE id IN (6,8)`. One solution could be `orderByRaw('FIELD(id,$sliced_ids)`, but 
the same holds true for `orderByRaw('RAND(aseed)')`...

Is there an efficient way to have pagination with a consistent random order between pages?

**EDIT: solution**

I'm exploring the possibility to use `inRandomOrder`, cache the Eloquent Collection and rebuild it. Something like:

```
 $posts = Cache::remember('posts', 30, function(){ 
     return serialize(Post::with('terms')->inRandomOrder()->get());
 });
 $posts = unserialize($posts);
```

In this case I think it's better to use `if (Cache::has('key')){...}`

**EDIT**

I don't know if it can be depend to the redis connection type: on tcp I have to serialize and unserialize, while on unix socket it works without serialize/unserialize